# Meaning of outlined boxes in chrome timeline

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

What is the difference between a solid (1) and an "outlined" (2) paint event in the Chrome timeline?

Why could I be getting nested (3) paint events?

[image: Pathological timeline]

**Update:**

Seems to indicate that the paint was "asynchronous": not executed during the Javascript phase. But if so, why is there no dimension information for these "outlined" paints. And again, why the nesting? Further reading appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I didn't read it too carefully, but Google has a huge documentation page for the Timeline Dev Tools in Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline

Comment: @BrianBennett I have read it pretty carefully, but I found no mention of these nested paint events, or the way they are presented.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In the dev tools timeline, what are the empty green rectangles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392133/in-the-dev-tools-timeline-what-are-the-empty-green-rectangles)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of that, @KonradDzwinel, cheers

Answer (score 2):

Recent answer by Paul Lewis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392133/in-the-dev-tools-timeline-what-are-the-empty-green-rectangles/27426601#27426601). Explanation by Jared Williams in the [official DevTools docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/devtools-docs/pull/207/files) (it seems that it haven't landed on production yet).

If you'd like to dig deeper into paint process, see [paint profiler](https://plus.google.com/+UmarHansa/posts/Bj19Qvf4bb7).